# Как сделать, чтобы страница пропорционально сжималась?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Привет всем! Вопрос такой: как сделать, чтобы при сжатии страницы, скажем, до 350px, она переставала подстраиваться под ширину экрана и начинала просто пропорционально сжиматься? То есть в коде написано, что ширина картинки = 300px, но после преодоления этого порога ширины, она сама пропорционально сжимается, так же и со шрифтами. Блоки при этом не плавают(т.е. ширина в % не подходит)

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос, Вам нужно чтобы сжимались картинки и шрифт, а не сами блоки? Если так, то стоит задать ширину в процентах самому <img>, а шрифтам значение в vw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body{
  /*В CSS Указываем минимальную ширину страницы*/
  min-width:350px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Вьюпорт без initial-scale (поместить в <head>)  -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no" />
```